# CSS Elements on top of other elements

Tags: html, css

I'm new to CSS and web development. I've read a few stack overflow articles related to positioning elements however I still can't get this to work. What I am trying to accomplish is the following:

1) background.png is always on the bottom.

2) anything in the class "header" is above the background.

3) anything in the class "navigation" is above the banner and positioned relative to banner.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="US-ASCII">
<title>My Title</title>
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>

<div class = "container">
    <div class = "background">
        <img class = "background-img" src="img/background.png">
    </div>

    <div class = "header">
        <img class ="banner" src ="img/banner.png">
        <div class = "navigation">
            <p>Everything under navigation will go overtop of banner</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




</body>

</html>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
@CHARSET "US-ASCII";

body, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, ol, li, dl, dt, dd, img, form, fieldset, blockquote {

    border: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0;

}

body {

    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif; line-height: 24px;
    background: #444444;
}


.container{
    width: 1400px;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0; right: 0; top: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

.background{
    z-index: -1;
}

.header{
    margin-top: 23px;
}

.banner{
    z-index: 2;
}

.navigation{
    z-index: 3;
}
```

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle with your code, please?

Comment: Also, you could state what's exactly the problem here. The way your question is being asked, it sounds like you want someone to code for you, and not to help you with your own code.

Comment: `z-index` only works when an element is positioned.

Comment: I.e. other than `static` positioning.

Answer (score 0):

To use the z-index property you must give a position to your elements. So in this example you must do something like this

```
    .header{
        margin-top: 23px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
    } 

   .navigation{
        z-index: 3;
        position: absolute;
    }
```